# PHP Command line don't execute command

Tags: php, xampp, command-line-interface, wamp, interactive

I installed xampp and put the php folder in my environment variable.

When I execute the "php filename.php" command, it always opens the interactive mode, it's the same with wamp.

Could someone help me? thank you

Comment: Maybe you have an alias that changes `php` to `php -a`?

Comment: If you're using bash, what does `type php` say?

Comment: @Barmar it's the same on bash. Here is the response with the alias command: alias ll='ls -l' / alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars' / alias node='winpty node.exe' / alias php='winpty php.exe'

Comment: You have `alias php = 'winpty php.exe'`. I don't know what `winpty` is, but I suspect that's part of the problem. It's probably not passing the filename argument.

Comment: I deleted it with `unalias` but it didn't change anything. Even `php -v` doesn't work :(.

Comment: What does `type php` say after you removed the alias?

Comment: that `php is aliased to 'winpty php.exe'`

Comment: Then you didn't properly remove the alias.

Comment: Use `\php filename.php`. The backslash  should prevent it from using the alias.

Comment: I just re-removed the alias and now I have this: `php is hashed (/c/xampp/php/php)`

Comment: `\php` doesn't work either

Comment: What if you use the absolute (full) path to the `php.exe` binary? What happens if you type `where php`? Perhaps even using `php.exe` rather than `php` would "fix" it

Comment: @h2ooooooo it does not work. `where php` shows me the path that I put in the environment variables.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.